# Tracking the beginning of a new Session in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

Hi I am trying to develop a functionality that will track everytime there is a new session created in a web app aka a user logs in.

I have created a class called "StateBag.cs"

```
using System;
using System.Text;

[Serializable()]
public class StateBag
{

    #region Business Methods

    // To catch the event of a New Session //
    private bool _NewSession = false;
    public bool NewSession
    {
        get { return _NewSession; }
        set { _NewSession = value; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

On the login page, just before login:-

```
// Declaration Region. //
private StateBag _Bag;



    if (Session.IsNewSession)
    {
        _Bag = new StateBag();
        _Bag.NewSession = true;
        // ViewState["StateBag"] = _Bag;
        Session["NewSession"] = _Bag;
    }
```

On the Main page, after a successful login:-

```
// Declaration region. //
StateBag _Bag
{
    get
    {
        return (StateBag)Session["NewSession"];
    }
}



    if (_Bag.NewSession == true)
    {

        // Do my stuff........ //

        _Bag.NewSession = false;  // set new Session back to false//
    }
```

I m having problems retrieving _Bag... it comes back as Null...

hence an error message :- 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Can anyone help me retrieve the NewSession property which I set to "True" on the login page?

Comment: Instead of rolling out your own solution use `Session_Start` event in global.asax

Comment: Can I use Session_Start outside of global.asax?? Because I need to be able to execute functionalities based on User Login information.. such as username, Name, ID, etc... these informations to my knowledge are not accessible from global.asax... hence my attempt to create my own solution.

Comment: @Philo: You can begin tracking the session in `global.asax` and then *update* that custom object to include user details when they become available.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing how I can track the Session start and then use that event trigger to execute my functionality on the Main page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing it in `ViewState`:

```
ViewState["StateBag"] = _Bag;
```

And retrieving it from `Session`:

```
return (StateBag)Session["NewSession"];
```

`ViewState` and `Session` are two completely different things, they don't share the same objects.  You need to pick one place to persist the data and always retrieve it from that same place.

Note: `ViewState` renders data to the *client*, so I wouldn't suggest using that to store anything that you don't want a client to be able to see/modify.

Comment: @Philo: `Session["NewSession"] = _Bag;`

Comment: ahh duh.. just figured that out.

Comment: tried doing that ... but _Bag still comes back as null.

Comment: @Philo: Can you edit your question to also include the updated code?  Are you sure your order of events is correct and that you're reading the object from `Session` *after* it's been written there?

Comment: ALright. I figured out my mistakes. Thank you David for pointing out the obvious flaws. I have a better understanding of Session and ViewState now. Thanks to you.